# How can I use and insert Brand and Model Rich Snippets properties?

Tags: php, html, rich-snippets

I wonder how I can use and implement the properties "Brand" and "model" for my schema.org/product.

My catalog is something like:
(e.g.)
Samsung (Brand) -> 32F5000 (Model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good boilerplate extension that tackles microdata for Magento:

https://github.com/LastRose/Magento-HTML5-Microdata

Specifically, see here:

https://github.com/LastRose/Magento-HTML5-Microdata/blob/master/app/design/frontend/default/html5-microdata/template/catalog/product/view.phtml#L40

In general, this will involve editing Magento's templates on its base or custom theme to mark up the tags. This is often a tedious process, hence my advice to use the project above to work from.

### Another Solution

Have you considered the JSON-LD implementation?
http://json-ld.org/

Schema.org gives examples of usage at the bottom of its schema pages:
http://schema.org/Product

This would avoid having to seek out each template for markup, and suffice depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks but I already implemented Rich Snippet on my template. I would like to know how to use these (brand and model) in particular. Do I need to use simple text in these properties? Or I need to put some specific urls?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. You can implement `Brand` as an `itemscope itemprop` node of `Product`, where the child elements would be treated as properties of that `Brand`. See the `Product` microdata schema example at the link referenced in my answer, and notice how they mark up an `AggregateRating` property as nested *inside* of the `Product` property.